# No method error advanced search ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an advanced search page with a separate search controller for my contracts. At the moment i am getting an error on my show page (search results) as i have recently changed my method in search.rb so it only shows records relating to the current_user.

I am using Devise.

Below is my search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base


  def self.user_search_contracts(user)
      user ||= User.new
      contracts = Contract.where(user_id: user.id)

    contracts = contracts.joins(:tenant).where(["tenants.first_name LIKE ? OR tenants.last_name LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", min_balance]) if min_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance <= ?", max_balance]) if max_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["unpaid_rent LIKE ?", unpaid_rent]) if unpaid_rent.present?

    return contracts
  end

end
```

show page for searches

```
.wrapper_with_padding
  #houses.clearfix
    - unless @search.user_search_contracts.blank?
      - @search.user_search_contracts.each do |contract|
        %a{ href: (url_for [contract])}
          .house
            %p.end_of_contract= contract.end_of_contract
            %p.balance= number_to_currency(contract.balance, :unit => "£", negative_format: "(%u%n)")
            -if contract.tenant.present?
              %p.tenant_id= contract.tenant.full_name
            -else
              %p No Tenant Assigned
            -if contract.house.present?
              %p.house_id= contract.house.full_house_name
            -else
              %p No Property Assigned
```

Error: undefined method `user_search_contracts' for #

Comment: What is `@search`? You kinda left that off but I am going to assume this is nil:NilClass and that you would greatly benefit for a [Wonderful Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) on rails and how it works? Also `user_search_contracts` would require an argument `user` yet twice you call it without one which will cause an issue.

Comment: That is the advanced search form

Comment: Please post the controller code that renders this view. You need to define `@search` in the controller action in order to use it in the view. Also, you defined the `self.user_search_contracts(user)` method as a class method (hint: `self`), and as the comment above suggests you're missing an argument (the `user`). You could, however, use it like `unless Search.user_search_contracts(current_user).blank?`.